# Difference in dates grouped by distinct users.

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe like this for example:

```
Date        |    UserId
2016-05-20  |      1100 
2016-05-22  |      1100
2016-05-23  |      1100
2016-05-25  |      1200
2016-05-26  |      1200
```

How do I find the difference in dates by Day/Week/Month for each distinct user since last entry. The output could look something like this:

```
Date        |    UserId  | Diff  
2016-05-20  |      1100  | 0
2016-05-22  |      1100  | 2 days
2016-05-23  |      1100  | 1 day
2016-05-25  |      1200  | 0
2016-05-26  |      1200  | 1 day
```

I know I'll have to use difftime() for this but can't wrap my head around the steps to do it for each distinct user and particularly can't figure out how to do it for each date in the same column of my data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Date` column is already a `Date` class, you can do using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,Diff:= c(0, diff.Date(Date)), .(UserId)]
df
         Date UserId Diff
1: 2016-05-20   1100    0
2: 2016-05-22   1100    2
3: 2016-05-23   1100    1
4: 2016-05-25   1200    0
5: 2016-05-26   1200    1
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Will familiarize myself with the data.table package for future reference I guess.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `ave` function is used to construct vectors calculated by group. If the class of the first column were still character or factor, then could have use `as.numeric(as.Date(Date))` as the first argument to `ave`.

```
dat <- read.table(text="Date|UserId
 2016-05-20|1100 
 2016-05-22|1100
 2016-05-23|1100
 2016-05-25|1200
 2016-05-26|1200", header = TRUE, sep="|", colClasses=c("Date", "numeric"))

dat$Diff= with(dat, ave(as.numeric(Date)  , UserId, FUN=function(x){c(0, diff(x) )}))
> dat
        Date UserId Diff
1 2016-05-20   1100    0
2 2016-05-22   1100    2
3 2016-05-23   1100    1
4 2016-05-25   1200    0
5 2016-05-26   1200    1
```